# How to run .jar file on Mac 10.11 without installing Java?

Tags: macos, java, jar

So I made an application using Java swing and converted it to a `.jar` file and would like to share it with my friend. However, he is not a programmer so his computer needs to install Java bloatware to run my simple application that is about 1 MB. I wouldn't want him to install so much just to execute the jar file, so is there a way for me to make the file executable in his computer? The excessive amount of stuff he has to install to make his computer compatible with jar files is making him reluctant to use my jar file

He uses a Macbook Pro Retina under El Capitan.

Comment: You can try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable/11556563#11556563 .

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like these solutions are not applicable to the latest OSX version.

Comment: The whole point of java(/python/.net/lua/etc) is that a developer can assume anyone can run the application provided they simply install a jre. this is much much easier than trying to deploy run-time for a machine complied language like C. you are setting yourself up for nothing but frustration by trying to destroy Java's primary innovation. installing jre is completely somthing any computer novice can do. If you can't make that assumption on a Mac, then you should stop developing in java, and find a technology that fits your needs better. You aren't telling him to install the jdk are you?